# Bios update after effects

Tags: operating-systems, desktop-computer

After updating the BIOS driver of my ACER laptop its will shown an error of no booting device found. What can I do? The older version of bios is 2.01 and after updating it become 2.1

Comment: If you can find the old version of BIOS, reinstall it from USB. See https://artiss.blog/2009/02/acer-aspire-one-bios/ , for example.